# Cyclomatic complexity for nested IFs

Tags: metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

While checking several descriptions/blogs/tutorials, I still don’t get how to calculate the McCabe metric for nested IFs. For example for the following pseudo code.

```
IF (CHECK_A() && CHECK_B() && CHECK_C()) {

    DO_SOMETHING()
}
```

This code can be written as following as well, representing the same logic.

```
IF (CHECK_A()) {

    IF (CHECK_B()) {

        IF (CHECK_C()) {

            DO_SOMETHING()

        }

    }

}
```

I assume this results in the following control flow graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6X28.png

Now, the cyclomatic complexity is calculated via `V(G) = e − n + 2p` while `e` being the # of edges, `n` being the # of nodes and `p` being the # of nodes that have exit points. Looking at the graph, `e = 7`, `n = 5` and `p = 1`, thus `V(G) = 7 − 5 + 2 * 1` = `4`. Can someone tell me whether this is the right way how to calculate it?